# implementation of a algorithm increment integer digits in java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, integer

I have a 6 digit integer.
How can I bump a each individual number so each number increases or decrease by 2?

ex."999999" to "111111"

I was thinking maybe spliting the number into pieces and then concatenating it back.

Comment: If you want people to take the time to answer your questions, please take the time to accept answers.  (Click on the tick next to the best answer.)

Comment: Ok now I am trying to find a way to do it with the % operator.

Comment: I would not actually call this "shift", because it is no shift. Anyway, I recently came across the problem of splitting an integer into its digits in Java and found it to be quite complicated to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be more efficient way, but if you are dealing only with 6 digits number, the performance issue is neglectable.

Iterate over digits [using the % and / operators on the original number], and for each digit, calculate its +2 value [with %10], and add it to the new number, with the approppriate exponent.

```
int x = 999999;
int $ = 0;
int exp = 0;
while (x > 0) { 
    int t = ((x % 10) +2) %10;
    $ += Math.pow(10, exp++) *t;
    x /= 10;
}
System.out.println($);
```

Note: it will break if the number implicitly contains zeros on the left [i.e. if 123 should be converted to 222345]. You can take care of it by iterating while `(exp < 6)` instead of `(x > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a mathematical operation or a "shift" in the bit-wise sense.  It is a string transformation problem.  I recommend that you:

1. turn the integer into a String
2. turn the String into an array of characters (decimal digits),
3. modifying the digits in the array,
4. turn the array back into a String, and
5. turn the String into an integer

If your number is provided as a String, you can skip the first and last steps.